# WSL: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to install MySQL on my WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 using this step: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database#install-mysql

But when I prompted `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and asked to enter a password I got this error `Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

After I bit googling I found most of the solution is with this command `mysql -u root -p` but I got another error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)`

I have started the sever with this command `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` it said the server is starting but I still got the ERROR 2002. I tried another command `sudo service mysql start` still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I installed MySQL in WSL2 recently.

First I installed `mysql-server` with `apt`.

> sudo apt install mysql-server

Next I did

> sudo service mysql start

And finally, I could run MySQL with

> sudo mysql

Apparantly, `mysql` will run taking root as the user when you use `sudo`, so `sudo` is necessary to run it.